# Как получить массив всех разделов на Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Требуется получить массив всех доступных для просмотра разделов жесткого диска, как это можно сделать? При установке библиотеки `driverlist` выдавало ошибку.

> rebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found
> (target=12.18.4 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
>
> E:\Важно\web\dev\rTelecomTask\webTotalCommanderFromMarEee\node_modules\drivelist>if
> not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
> rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
> rebuild ) gyp ERR! find Python gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set
> from command line or npm configuration gyp ERR! find Python Python is
> not set from environment variable PYTHON gyp ERR! find Python checking
> if "python" can be used

Comment: Разделов чего? Жесткого диска? Документа Word? Сайта kremlin.ru?

Comment: @Yaant Жесткого диска, да, всех которые есть на пк

Comment: Список дисковых разделов - платформозависимая штука, так что лучше не изобретать велосипед, а поискать библиотеку на npm. Возможно подойдёт https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist

Comment: @nörbörnën она у меня не ставится почему- то

Comment: @entithat посмотрите ошибку, добавил ее в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы не установили переменную среды, поэтому не устанавливается библиотека.

> gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm
> configuration gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment
> variable PYTHON

Установите переменную среды:

```
set PYTHON=D:\Python\bin\Python.exe
```

Или таким образом:

1. Мой компьютер > Свойства

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Advanced > Переменные окружения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Ищем Path и нажимаем Edit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Кнопка "Добавить" > Добавляем путь к директории с Python > Ok

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем это требуется вообще? и к чему тут python?

Comment: В прилагаемом тексте с ошибкой было четко сказано, что не найден питон.

Comment: Ааа, так вот почему у меня не компилировалось приложение в Visual Studio для ондроед на С++

Comment: @entithat почитайте, пожалуйста, текст ошибки из-за которой не устанавливается библиотека. Его можно посмотреть в предыдущих версиях вопроса

Comment: А, вижу. Пакет driverlist питон использует чёли

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [эту библиотеку](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-disk-info).

```
const nodeDiskInfo = require("node-disk-info");

try {
  const disks = nodeDiskInfo.getDiskInfoSync();
  printResults(disks);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

function printResults(disks) {
  for (const disk of disks) {
    console.log("Filesystem:", disk.filesystem);
    console.log("Capacity:", disk.capacity);
    console.log("Mounted:", disk.mounted, "\n");
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Filesystem: Local Fixed Disk
Capacity: 83%
Mounted: C: 

Filesystem: Local Fixed Disk
Capacity: 68%
Mounted: D:
```